# Different actuator (management server) port changes HTTP response

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-chaos-monkey

I am having a hard time in Chaos Monkey For Spring Boot regarding error responses when a user POSTs an invalid (like `{"level": -2}`update via REST to our actuator endpoint where one can update options of the behavior of CMSB (only positive levels are allowed). In the first image, I set the `management.server.port` to `8888` and the app port to `8080`. When posting a new property to the CMSB REST API I am getting the following response (which is not what we would have expected): 
[image: wrong response]

And in case I leave the management port at the same port the same as the app I am getting the following response:
[image: correct response]

For both cases we would have expected the same error response (the second one). So we're asking us (at CMSB) whether this is an intended behavior of spring boot and if not, what our options are to get around writing our own error response handler in case the management port is different from the app port. 
Please note that this is not about the intended behavior of chaos monkey for spring boot but rather about whether this is a spring boot bug or not. In both cases we would like to have a detailed error response so a user knows what's wrong. Under the hood we are using the `@Validated` annotation in combination with something like this to validate inputs:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Validated
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class AssaultPropertiesUpdate {
    @Nullable
    @Min(value = 1)
    @Max(value = 10000)
    private Integer level;
```

On a side note: in both cases the error message in the logs is correct. But only in the second case is this error message

> `WARN 4477 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> de.codecentric.spring.boot.chaos.monkey.endpoints.ChaosMonkeyRestEndpoint.updateAssaultProperties(de.codecentric.spring.boot.chaos.monkey.endpoints.AssaultPropertiesUpdate): [Field error in object 'assaultPropertiesUpdate' on field 'level': rejected value [-2]; codes [Min.assaultPropertiesUpdate.level,Min.level,Min.java.lang.Integer,Min]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [assaultPropertiesUpdate.level,level]; arguments []; default message [level],1]; default message [must be greater than or equal to 1]] ]`

used as the response payload.

Minimal example project: https://github.com/fletchgqc/mediator 
Start the project with `mvn spring-boot:run`. and then do a POST against `http://localhost:8080/actuator/chaosmonkey/assaults` with the the payload: `{"level": -2}`. Correct error response should be shown (like in image 2).

Then stop the project, to https://github.com/fletchgqc/mediator/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties add `management.server.port=8888` and start the app again. Do a POST against `http://localhost:8888/actuator/chaosmonkey/assaults` with the same payload as before. The wrong error message should appear (like in image 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the spring team fixed it here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21036